# Put the image above the information

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

I have a image that there is a spinner that spin around it by animation and also there is a two boxes that contain information as shown in the image uploaded below and the image is beside the boxes but  I want the image to be above the boxes.

[image: The Result]

```css
.about-img {
    position: relative;
    width: 25rem;
    height: 25rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.about-img .spin{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0);
    width: 68%;
    height: 68%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: .2rem solid var(--main-color);
    border-bottom: .2rem solid var(--main-color);
    border-left: .2rem solid var(--main-color-alt);
    border-right: .2rem solid var(--main-color-alt);
    animation: aboutSpinner 8s linear infinite;
}
.team-page {
    display: flex;
    position: relative  ;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 10px 5%;
}
.footer {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.about,.skills {
    padding: 40px;
    min-height: 330px;
}
.about {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
.about h3 {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.skills {
    background-color: #3366cc;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    height: 0;
}
.skills h2 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.skills .progress {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.about-img .image {
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 60%;
    border: .2rem solid var(--main-color-alt);
}
```

```html
  <div class="team-page">
      <div class="about-img disable_curet">
          <img class="image" src="imgs/logo.png" alt="">
          <span class="spin"></span>
      </div>
      <section class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="about">
                          <h3>Profile</h3>
                          <p>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis voluptas temporibus a eveniet odio consequuntur, aspernatur fugit voluptatum laboriosam id unde voluptates modi quos omnis et numquam ipsa doloribus debitis.
                          </p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="skills">
                          <h2>Our skills</h2>
                          <strong>PHP MySQL</strong>
                          <span class="pull-right"70%></span>
                          <div class="progress">
                              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 70%;"></div>
                          </div>
                          <strong>UI/UX</strong>
                          <span class="pull-right"85%></span>
                          <div class="progress">
                              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 85%;"></div>
                          </div>
                          <strong>Bootstrap</strong>
                          <span class="pull-right"95%></span>
                          <div class="progress">
                              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 95%;"></div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </section>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer">
      <!-- The Paragraph at the End -->
      <p class="copyright">&copy; 2023 <span title="Science Lab Team | Sands International School">SLT | SIS</span> All right Reserved</p>
  </div>
```

Help if you can, to move the image above the boxes.

Comment: You have `.team-page` set up as a flex container that lays out its children as columns, if you don't want that ... well then don't _do_ that.

Answer (score 1):

Try display:block for the .team-page class like this :

```css
.about-img {
    position: relative;
    width: 25rem;
    height: 25rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.about-img .spin{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0);
    width: 68%;
    height: 68%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: .2rem solid var(--main-color);
    border-bottom: .2rem solid var(--main-color);
    border-left: .2rem solid var(--main-color-alt);
    border-right: .2rem solid var(--main-color-alt);
    animation: aboutSpinner 8s linear infinite;
}
.team-page {
    display: block;
    position: relative  ;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 10px 5%;
}
.footer {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.about,.skills {
    padding: 40px;
    min-height: 330px;
}
.about {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
.about h3 {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.skills {
    background-color: #3366cc;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    height: 0;
}
.skills h2 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.skills .progress {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.about-img .image {
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 60%;
    border: .2rem solid var(--main-color-alt);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="team-page">
    <div class="about-img disable_curet">
        <img class="image" src="imgs/logo.png" alt="">
        <span class="spin"></span>
    </div>
    <section class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="about">
                        <h3>Profile</h3>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis voluptas temporibus a eveniet odio consequuntur, aspernatur fugit voluptatum laboriosam id unde voluptates modi quos omnis et numquam ipsa doloribus debitis.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="skills">
                        <h2>Our skills</h2>
                        <strong>PHP MySQL</strong>
                        <span class="pull-right"70%></span>
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 70%;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <strong>UI/UX</strong>
                        <span class="pull-right"85%></span>
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 85%;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <strong>Bootstrap</strong>
                        <span class="pull-right"95%></span>
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 95%;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <!-- The Paragraph at the End -->
    <p class="copyright">&copy; 2023 <span title="Science Lab Team | Sands International School">SLT | SIS</span> All right Reserved</p>
</div>
```